# Calculate deposit amount when adding to a liquidity pool in Uniswap v3

Tags: solidity, uniswap, defi

Suppose:

- The price of an A/B token pair is `price_now`
- The user wants to provide liquidity in the range `price_low` to `price_high` such that `price_low < price_now < price_high`
- The user supplies `X` amount of token A

[image: Create new Uniswap v3 position]

What amount of token B needs to be deposited? For example 2907.47 USDC would be needed if I want to supply 1 ETH in the screenshot. I need a math formula.

Comment: did you solved this? I need help with this also :/

Comment: @buckyass see kfx answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question, first you need to calculate the liquidity `Liquidity_x` that is provided by the asset `x` given the current price and price range. From the [whitepaper](https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf) it can be derived  that if the current price is within the range then:

```
Liquidity_x = x * sqrt(price) * sqrt(price_high) / (sqrt(price_high) - sqrt(price))
```

See [this article](http://atiselsts.github.io/pdfs/uniswap-v3-liquidity-math.pdf) for more details. Alternatively, this is the formula for `Liquidity_y` if you have the amount of `y` known:

```
Liquidity_y = y / (sqrt(price) - sqrt(price_low))
```

Then you should use the fact that the goal is to have an optimally balanced position, where `Liquidity_y` == `Liquidity_x`. (Explanation: to calculate the liquidity of a position where the current price is within the price range, Uniswap uses the minimum of the liquidities provided by the two tokens in that position. If the amount of one token is more than necessary, the extra liquidity provided is essentially ignored from a LP perspective. So your goal to have such an amount of `y` in the pool such that the liquidity of `y` exactly matches the liquidity of `x` : `Liquidity_x` is equal to `Liquidity_y`.)

Solving the second equation above for `y` you get:

```
y = Liquidity_y * (sqrt(price) - sqrt(price_low))
```

In the example:

```
x = 1
price = 2486.8
price_high = 2998.9
price_low = 1994.2
L = x * sqrt(price) * sqrt(price_high) / (sqrt(price_high) - sqrt(price))
# L = 557.9599554712883 in the example
y = L * (sqrt(price) - sqrt(price_low))
```

The result `y` value is 2907.729524805772 USDC which is pretty close to what UI shows.

Comment: There probably is an error in your calculation, I get y = 2909.48USDC, as expected
This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @SimonVanMachin thanks, updated

Answer (score 2):

The best place for the equations behind liquidity allocation is the V3 whitepaper
https://uniswap.org/whitepaper-v3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/base/LiquidityManagement.sol#L51

https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/libraries/LiquidityAmounts.sol#L56

https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-core/blob/main/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol#L327

use amount0 user inputed and lower/upper price to calculate liquidityDelta => use liquidityDelta to culate exact amount0 and amout1 => display at frontend

Comment: How to calculate "liquidity exactly? This is from ET/USDC pool output.                           sqrtRatioX96: JSBI(4) [ -1584226589, 214491545, -1833477807, 22349, sign: false ],
  liquidity: JSBI(2) [ -1843001346, -471987084, sign: false ],
  tickCurrent: 200301, What does it mean ? @saiwaixiaowangzi